# PHP PDO gives an error when execute()

Tags: php, pdo

I am attempting to insert data into database via PDO

Here is my snippet:

```
try {
        $count = count($db_data);
        for ($i=0; $i < $count ; $i++) { 
            $query_string = "INSERT INTO data (" . $fields[$i] . ") VALUES(" . $values[$i] . ")";
            echo $query_string;
            $vle = $dbh->prepare($query_string);

            $vle->bindValue(':USER', $db_data[$i]['user']);
            $vle->bindValue(':SERVER_NAME', $db_data[$i]['server_name']);
            $vle->bindValue(':SERVER_NAME', $db_data[$i]['description']);
            $vle->bindValue(':PATH', $db_data[$i]['path']);
            $vle->bindValue(':DATE', $db_data[$i]['date']);
            $vle->execute();

            echo "KEY: " . $fields[$i] . "</br>" . "VALUES: " . $values[$i] . "</br>";
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

But I am getting following error:

Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

**EDIT**

`$query_string` is:

```
INSERT INTO data (user, server_name, description, path, date) VALUES(:jsieclaf, :srvc07.gnotek.com>, :php.nested.base64.526, :a:1:{i:0;s:70:" /home/jsieclaf/public_html/modules/mod_araticl= hess/mod_araticlhess";}, :Mon, 7 Apr 2014 13:48:56 +0300)
```

$db_data is:

```
array (size=5)   

'user' => string ':jhjju' (length=9)   
'server_name' => string ':sjvbg07.gnotek.com>' (length=20)   
'description' => string ':php.nested.bade454.526' (length=22)   
'path' => string ':a:1:{i:0;s:70:" /home/jhjju/public_html/modules/mod_araticl=     hess/mod_ereticlhess";}' (length=89)   
'date' => string ':Mon, 7 Apr 2014 13:48:56 +0300' (length=31)
```

Comment: what does echo $query_string; ?

Comment: Simple debugging is in order... Please post `print_r($db_data)` so we can see what you started with, and `echo $query_string;` to see what statement it produces.

Comment: the whole point of PDO is to prepare statment but you still concatenate SQL string

Comment: Post it by editing above please, not in the comments.  Looks like you are not making use of parameter placeholders at all but rather just stuffing values into the SQL string.

Comment: That's messed up. How did you populate `$db_data`? You have prepended `:` onto all the _values_, rather than onto the field names as placeholders for the values. That isn't at all how placeholders work.

Comment: Pleas post the code where the array `$db_data` is populated because that's the first part of your problem.

Comment: So, you see nothing strange in such a query string?

Comment: That query string is very strange, and like the previous commentator said, its messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName (" . implode(',', array_keys($assoc_array)) . ") VALUES (" . trim(str_repeat('?,', count($assoc_array)), ',') . ")";

$stm = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array_values($assoc_array));
```

Comment: Thanks @Sid Hussain! when I var_dump my $assoc_array:

    `array (size=5)
  0 => string 'jsiespaf' (length=8)
  1 => string 'srvc07.gnotek.com>' (length=19)
  2 => string 'php.nested.base64.526' (length=21)
  3 => string 'a:1:{i:0;s:70:" /home/jsieclaf/public_html/modules/mod_araticl=
hess/mod_araticlhess";}' (length=88)
  4 => string 'Mon, 7 Apr 2014 13:48:56 +0300' (length=30)`

I got this above.
My question is how can I apply your statement with this. Statement:

    `trim(str_repeat('?,', count($assoc_array)), ',') . ")";`

Comment: curiozity, array_keys will give you the array keys, using implode, all the keys are joined together using ",", then next part deals with place holder, the "?" can be used as a placeholder in this case , you need to know how many "?" to use, that's where str_repeat is used, using the count of array elements. finally the last "," is removed. You don't need to use bindValue in this case, because you are not binding a name/value parameter. The the statement I gave , you don't need the for loop, just put the statements, i gave in your try/catch.

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName (" . implode(',', array_keys($assoc_array)) . ") VALUES (" . trim(str_repeat('?,', count($assoc_array)), ',') . ")";
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array_values($assoc_array));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Which of your two answers is actually an answer?

Comment: The above code is refactored, to show, you dont need what you had before in the try/catch. This is my actual answer.